# Python Pil Change GreyScale Tif To RGB

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I have a greyscale TIF File. I need to convert it to RGB/ read from it in a way I can work with it.

```
img = Image.open(GIF_FILENAME)
rgbimg = img.convert('RGB')
for i in range(5):
    print rgbimg.getpixel((i, 0))
```

The convert.("RGB") will automatically make everything (255,255,255) even though the picture is a really dark mostly black picture.

If I just read the greyscale numbers I get numbers from around 1400 to 1900.

I need to also save a copy of the picture as a RGB Jpeg.
Picture in question:  [Here]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuNJh.jpg

How would I go along doing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

what about:

```
img = Image.open(GIF_FILENAME)
rgbimg = Image.new("RGBA", img.size)
rgbimg.paste(img)
rgbimg.save('foo.jpg')
```

[EDIT]

created a test:

```
from PIL import Image
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

img = Image.open("kEwfFs3.png")
rgbimg = Image.new("RGBA", img.size)
rgbimg.paste(img)

found_colors = defaultdict(int)
for x in range(0, rgbimg.size[0]):
    for y in range(0, rgbimg.size[1]):
        pix_val = rgbimg.getpixel((x, y))
        found_colors[pix_val] += 1 
pprint.pprint(dict(found_colors))

rgbimg.save('kEwfFs3.jpg')
```

And that outputs:

```
{(0, 0, 0, 255): 747802,
 (1, 1, 1, 255): 397,
 (2, 2, 2, 255): 299,
 (3, 3, 3, 255): 255,
 (4, 4, 4, 255): 221,
 (5, 5, 5, 255): 200,
 (6, 6, 6, 255): 187,
 (7, 7, 7, 255): 138,
 (8, 8, 8, 255): 160,
 (9, 9, 9, 255): 152,
 (10, 10, 10, 255): 122,
 (11, 11, 11, 255): 116,
 (12, 12, 12, 255): 144,
 (13, 13, 13, 255): 117,
 (14, 14, 14, 255): 117,
 (15, 15, 15, 255): 102,
 (16, 16, 16, 255): 119,
 (17, 17, 17, 255): 299641,
 (18, 18, 18, 255): 273,
 (19, 19, 19, 255): 233,
.................... etc .......
.................... etc .......
 (249, 249, 249, 255): 616,
 (250, 250, 250, 255): 656,
 (251, 251, 251, 255): 862,
 (252, 252, 252, 255): 1109,
 (253, 253, 253, 255): 1648,
 (254, 254, 254, 255): 2964175}
```

Which is what you would expect.
Is your output different?

Comment: Thanks so much! Only correction to your code would be  .past(img) instead of paste(im)

Comment: You are welcome. Correction to your correction would be .paste(img) instead of .past(img)   ;)

Comment: Is there a way to work with the image without having to save it before? The same error (255,255,255,255) happens if I try to work with the picture before saving it.

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample image, or can you put it in the question?

Comment: Imgur Changed the Picture to a PNG File. But If I run it on the tiff file, the outputted JPG looks like http://imgur.com/qtQTJKQ For some reason it only reads the black or white. Not the inbetween.

Also My color thingi, only gives me the even numbers (0,0,0) then (2,2,2)

Comment: Would the fact that it is a 16 bit tiff help/change the situation?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with an `I;16` (16-bit grayscale) tiff, converted to RGB. Some [digging into the manual](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.convert) reveals the problem has to do with the lut PIL is using to convert grayscale images to RGB. It is working in an 8-bit color space; that is it clips all values above 255. So a quick and simple solution is to manually convert to RGB using your own lut which scales the values within range using the [point](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.point) method like so:

```
path = 'path\to\image'
img = Image.open(path)
img.point(lambda p: p*0.0039063096, mode='RGB')
img = img.convert('RGB')
img.show() # check it out!
```

I determined the "lut" formula by just dividing 256 by the 16-bit equivalent, 65535.